# Is there a way to know which ntp reply package for an ntp request package in language c?

Tags: c, linux, networking, ntp

I'm capturing ntp reply packets and i want to know witch reply packet for request packet? is there a field that specify this info? how can i do that in C langage? 
thank you

Comment: Which NTP version? You can see the full specifications in the RFC for your NTP version, including sample code.

Comment: When you sent an NTP packet, you filled in the *originate* field with your machine's time.  The returned packet will have the same value in that field.  So that's what you should match on.